# wordpress installation failed with nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am using nginx/1.20.1, PHP 7.2.34, mysqld 8.0.27 on CentOS7. I can open the wordpress index page but the installation always failed. I am sure that my username, password, and hostnames are correct (even if I add more users or reset the passwords), but it says:

Error establishing a database connection:
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

I tried to create my own wp-config.php file and set the configuration, then it would be a HTTP ERROR 500. The log says:
PHP Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-load.php on line 50
I don't know why mine is line 50 but others are 37. Howeverm, I already change the ownership of html(and even www) folder fo to nginx, and changed all the files in them to 777, but it is still not working.

I think MySQL is not connected to the wordpress but the 3306 port is open:
tcp6    0    0 :::3306            :::*         LISTEN    31913/mysqld
and it still did not work when I did:
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306' );
in wp-config.php

I tired WP-DEBUG but it did not show because of the HTTP ERROR 500. What else can I do now

Answer (score 0):

**Are you sure you entered the username and password correctly for the MySQL user?**

If you're still unsure:

- create a new database
- define a new user in the database
- and then retest.

[Here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-new-mysql-user-account-grant-privileges) are instructions for creating a new user and granting permissions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I wonder if I used the wrong password, would it also be HTTP ERROR 500?

Comment: @jeffma Have you checked if MySQL is enabled and running on your server?

Comment: it is active, and I even restarted it

Comment: @jeffma Do you have another PHP project on the server using MySQL in addition to this WordPress project?

Comment: No, I only use this WordPress project. But if this is a conflict, how do I check it. In fact, I reloaded server but it is still the same problem

Comment: @jeffma I suggest that, once again, with the help of [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-7), you install the WordPress stage on your server.

Comment: Like I said, when I created my own wp-config.php, it would be HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @jeffma Paste the contents of the wp-config.php file in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/), and then link it here for review

Comment: I solved it! Look at the answer I just posted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I read and learned this from somewhere else:
Running a test PHP program to connect MySQL

```
<PHP
<?PHP
$connect =mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
if (!$connect) {
die('error'. mysqli_error());
}
echo 'success';
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

and it returns:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in /home/test.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in /home/test.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/test.php on line 7
```

My current PHP does not support the verification method demanded(caching_sha2_password), the default for PHP is mysql_native_password.
I altered it with

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

And it worked.